Bear spray in vehicle - risk of leak causing accident
I carry bear spray when working and camping in the bush in Eastern Ontario.
SABRE Wild Bear Spray (225 G)
I travel with the bear spray in the cab  of my truck. It has occurred to me that the bear spray canister could malfunction or get damaged and leak into the air in the cab, causing an accident.
What can be done to mitigate this risk? For example, store the spray in an airtight case of some kind. Or find a way to store the spray outside in the bed of the truck. (I don't have a truck toolbox.)

Other concerns include discharge due to excessive heat/cold or pressure changes (e.g. due to elevation change).

While the potential consequences are fairly high, the overall risk is quite low. While not many people overall have bear spray in their truck, many do have any number of things like shaving cream and what not that survive just fine.

I would suggest exactly what you have proposed. Find some reasonably airtight container. That might be as simple as using a ziploc bag

There are dedicated "bear spray safety containers" to be had for less than $20CAD.
It's not necessarily a high risk, but it's not entirely unknown either.  For example, it's apparently illegal/problematic to carry them in a general aviation plane.  See also backcountry pilot site
I keep mine in the trunk of my car, but would be somewhat leery of having in the cabin proper all the time.

An added bonus with that container is that it's big enough to hold a holster as well. No need to store the holster separately. Make a clip-on bear spray holster.
